# Закрытая и открытая экспонеты ключа RSA

Tags: математика, шифрование, rsa

В каком случае закрытая экспонента ключа RSA будет равна открытой экспоненте?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin можете объяснить, почему никогда?

Comment: Хотя бы потому, что у них [длина](http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/) разная.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin разве это следует из (e * d) % phi(n) = 1? Если да, то как?

Comment: @Rootware разве это следует из (e * d) % phi(n) = 1? Если да, то как?

Comment: Обозначения с википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA

Comment: Предлагаю минусующим объяснить, в чём проблема

Comment: Полагаю, что минусующий сам плохо знаком с теорией конечных полей Галуа и слабыми сторонами криптосистемы RSA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если закрытый ключ - пара чисел (d,N), а открытый ключ - пара чисел (e,N), где N=p*q. функция Эйлера в таком случае Fi(N) = (p-1)(q-1).
между ключами существует связь вида: (e * d) mod Fi(N) = 1. Отсюда очевидно, что -1 * -1 = 1, а -1 mod Fi(N) = Fi(N) - 1.

Пример:
p=23, q=11 => N = 253, Fi(253)=22*10=220 => если e=-1 mod 220 = 220-1=219 то (219*219) mod 220 = 1.
то есть при (d=219, N=253) => (e=219, N=253).

Comment: Можете подробней пояснить, что за -1? Пример подходит, согласен

Comment: Могу, но краткость моего ответа зависит от глубині Ваших знаний :) Fi(N)-1 всегда будет взаимно простім с функцией Эйлера, это очевидно из алгоритма Эвклида. Чтобы этого избежать надо просто не выбирать значения Fi(N)-1.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что чтобы они были равны, достаточно чтобы Fi(N)-1 было взаимно простым с Fi(N)? Тогда мы просто полагаем e=d=Fi(N)-1

Comment: Вы правильно поняли. А -1 это следчтвие цикличности отображения области допустимых значений на числовую ось. -1 = Fi(N) - 1, -2=Fi(N)-2, ...

Comment: И ещё: существуют ли такие p и q, при которых e=d ВСЕГДА (это основной вопрос в принципе, т.к. о существовании я догадывался)?

Comment: Существует, при p=1, q=2. ;)

Comment: А есть какая-нибудь проверка на p и q (условие), которая скажет, что для этих p и q e=d всегда?

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам понравился, можете ещё нажать стрелочку вверх ;)

Comment: Я нажал, но у меня репутация низкая - не учитывается. Так что, можно условие такое сформулировать?

Comment: Нет, в алгебраическом кольце есть только один единичный элемент по умножению. Другое дело, если для построения криптосистемы использовать слабые простые числа, то тогда шифрование и расшифровка создают короткие циклы значений, иногда с периодом повторения даже 1, т.е. m^e mod N = m. Но это уже из другой оперы.

Comment: Ещё пару слов. Ситуация, которая вас интересует, возможна в случае, если НОД(e, Fi(N)) > 1. Однако этот случай устраняется на этапе выбора открытого ключа, поэтому кроме e=d=Fi(N)-1 эта коллизия более не встречается.